# Filtering specific checkboxes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this code:

```
<form method="post">
    <% for(let i = 0; i < websites.length; i++){ let website = websites[i]; %>
    <fieldset id="site<%= i %>" style="padding-bottom: 0;
                padding-top: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 0;">
        <label for="checkbox<%= i %>">Attach BuiltWith results (cost 1 credit)</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox<%= i %>" id="checkbox<%= i %>">
        <p style="color: <% if(errorMsgs[i] === 'Wrong website address'){ %> red;<% } else { %> green;<% } %>
                padding-bottom: 0;
                padding-top: 0;
                margin-bottom: 0;"
           class="">
            <%= errorMsgs[i] %>
        </p>
        <div class="">
            <input class="website"
                   name="website<%= i %>"
                   id="<%= i %>"
                   value="<%= website %>"
                   type="text"/>
            <a href="/websites/edit/<%= i %>"
               class="btn btn-info hide">
                Edit
            </a>
            <a href="/websites/delete/<%= i %>"
               data-id="<%= i %>"
               class="btn btn-danger confirmation removeBtn">
                Remove
            </a>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <% } %>
    <input type="submit"
           id="generateReport"
           class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-2"
           value="Generate a report"
           name="generateReport"
           data-toggle="modal"
           data-target="#exampleModal">
    <!-- Save button created using Javascript. In case JS is disabled -->
</form>
```

The `<%%>` thing is [EJS templating system](http://www.embeddedjs.com/). This is what I'm doing in the back end:

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    var checkboxes = Object.keys(req.body)
        .filter(key => key.startsWith('checkbox'))
        .map(k => req.body[k]);
    console.log(checkboxes);

    res.redirect('/reports');
});
```

What I want to achieve: As you see there can be many websites, to be sent to the back end. I need to attach a checkbox to each of them. Unfortunately, what I'm getting now is this:

```
[ 'on' ]
```

which is not what I want.

I basically need to know which checkboxes specifically were checked. How can I do it?

Edit: This is the req.body outprint

```
{ checkbox0: 'on',
    website0: 'google.com',
    website1: 'stackoverflow.com' }
```

This worked for me:

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    var bwIndexes = [];
    var checkboxes = Object.keys(req.body)
        .filter(key => key.startsWith('checkbox'))
        .map(k => bwIndexes.push(k.slice(-1)));
    console.log(bwIndexes);
    console.log(req.body);

    res.redirect('/reports');
});
```

Comment: You can print `req.body` on console and show output in your question

Comment: Ok this makes sense. But how can I get it to give me the index?

Comment: you are filtering `checkbox` that is output is correct others start with  `website`

Comment: Yes. But I need the indexes. The 0 at the end of checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will work if your index is between 0 to 9

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    var bwIndexes = [];
    var checkboxes = Object.keys(req.body)
        .filter(key => key.startsWith('checkbox'))
        .map(k => bwIndexes.push(k.slice(-1)));
    console.log(bwIndexes);
    console.log(req.body);

    res.redirect('/reports');
});
```

following will work even index more than 9

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    var bwIndexes = [];
    var checkboxes = Object.keys(req.body)
        .filter(key => key.startsWith('checkbox'))
        .map(k => bwIndexes.push(k.replace( /^\D+/g, '')));
    console.log(bwIndexes);
    console.log(req.body);

    res.redirect('/reports');
});
```

Comment: The logic helped, thank you, the code doesn't work though. I'll add the code that worked for me in the question. If you edit the code so it works, I'll select as best answer

Comment: I updated code, I hope you understand problem(if index more than 9)